# How can I compare each row in table with the below one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How could I compare value in a row with the below one .. and this for all records

```
EX.
Name      Age
Ahmed     20
Marko     22
jouhn     18
mira      30
joi       19
```

so I want the result :

```
Ahmed < Marko
Marko > jouhn
Jouhn < Mira
Mira  > joi
```

could anyone help me on this?

Comment: "below" in what sense/order?

Comment: @ypercube He made it rather clear that it was based on age.

Comment: Is it based on the age? why Ahmed > Marko ? 20 is < than 22

Comment: sorry it was my mistake i have changed Ahmed < Marko

Comment: @ypercube there is no order as in actual this table is the in between many2many tbles .. so there is no order ..

Comment: ypercube's question actually has a point. Why Marko appears "below" Ahmed, but not jouhn?

Comment: If there is no order, (e.g no other column that you can base the ordering on), what do you want the query to show? The comparisons based on random orderings?

Comment: ok we can compare regarding to name ?

Comment: Yes, just change the `order by id` in @valex's answer with `order by name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/459c0/10)

```
with t1 as
(
  select t.*, 
   row_number() over (order by id) rn
  from t
 )

select t1.Name as Name1, 
       case when t1.Age>t2.Age 
          then '>'
            when t1.Age<t2.Age 
          then '<'
            else '='
       end as SIGN,
       t2.Name as Name2 
  from t1
  join t1 as t2 on t1.rn+1 = t2.id ;
```

Comment: In 2012 version, you can also use the `LAG()` or `LEAD()` function for this.

Comment: (t1.rn+1=t2.id) could we change this condition with any other condetion related to name .. because there is no ID in this Table??

Comment: To get NEXT record you have to define an order in your table. If there is no order in your query then order is not predetermined. So if you need another order just change the field name in the `row_number() over (order by id)` to for example `row_number() over (order by name)`.